# how to import tesseract in rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hello I'm trying to import the JavaScript library tesseract.js in a new rails 7 apps, I am able to add the library using yarn:

```
yarn add terresact.js
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "tesseract.js": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

and my aplication.js

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "tesseract.js"
```

but is not working I have one file.js to test and is not recognizing the code:

```
const player = document.getElementById('player');
const snapshotZone = document.getElementById('snapshot');
const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
 player.srcObject = stream
})

captureButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const context = snapshot.getContext('2d')
  context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, snapshotZone.width, snapshotZone.height)
  
  Tesseract.recognize(snapshotZone, 'eng', { logger: m => console.log(m) }) // 英語
    .then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    result.value = text
  })
})
```

I get this code fron codepen and there is working how can I import correctly tesseract.js?

Comment: 1. What error do you get? 2. Why do you import it in a different file than the one you are using it int?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tesseract.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: I'm importing in the aplication.js file that is the main js file that manage all other files.

Comment: How do you bundle your application? To import node modules in the browser you have to use a bundler like webpack or vite

Comment: Is a fresh rails 7 app with the standard set up. If I'm not wrong rails 7 is using jbuilder